# How to convert/encode video files with ffmpeg, using AMD Radeon hardware encoding

Tags: hardware, radeon, ffmpeg, encoding

Good day, and thanks in advance for any help

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a PC with an AMD Ryzen 7  5700G CPU and AMD Radeon RX 6600 GPU.

I have a large number of video files in MP4 format that I need to encode and burn subtitles (times and dates in subtitle format) into. The command `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf subtitles=subtitle.srt out.mp4` works just fine.

HOWEVER, I want to use the Radeon GPU's hardware encoding, because it is a very large number of files, and it maxes out the CPU, which means I sometimes struggle to do something else at the same time.

I have been googling and searching for answers, but the best I can find is to use the `-hwaccel opencl` command line option, which doesn't work and gives errors, or the `-hwaccel vaapi` command line option, which just uses the CPU instead of the GPU again.

Can anyone please kindly point me in the right direction? I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have Ubuntu with AMD Ryzen 7 4800U.

Comment: @Andrew No, I'm afraid not. Is there no way to do this? That seems impossible, since AMD's drivers are open-source and included with most Linux distributions.